# Advanced hotspots analysis by Intel Vtune Amplifier XE2016 of a VS2015 console application not working

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, intel, intel-vtune

When executing the Intel "Advanced Hotspots, stacks and context switches analysis" (or higher) of my simple (a few lines) VS2015 console C++ (native) application, its processing hangs and Windows restart is needed, see the sample solution and screen captures enclosed in the zip file). The same applies for larger solutions... ". The "Basic Hotspots" and "Advanced Hotspots without stacks..." works fine. 
Can anybody help?

The solution and screen captures of the hotspots settings:

https://app.box.com/s/ihb51o9cxrn8y7li6eupa9o7qbkof4dp

Windows 10Pro 64bit Build 1607, Intel Core I7-4771
VS2015 Community V. 14.0.25431.01 Updt. 3
Intel VTume Ampl. XE2016 Updt 2, build 444464
Thanks for help!!!!

Answer (score 0):

This issue should be fixed in the VTune Amplifier 2017 XE.